# Searching structured data in a database (Fulltext + query)

Tags: python, database, search, full-text-search, relational-database

In the application i work i need to search the database for text (full text search) and prioritize the result based on other columns. Which kind of datastore is best here by considering performance? I need to search the structured data and prioritize the result.

Is it RDBMS or document store (Couch, Mongo) or any other NoSQL database? Or should i use batch processing tools such as Hadoop and prepare the data for search?

I am looking for directions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a month ago i had a similar problem and wanted to know if there are hard facts, accountable meassurements for performance benefits of a nosql solution.

So i googled for comparisions and found this [neat test](http://blog.pingoured.fr/index.php?post/2012/05/20/PostgreSQL-vs-MongoDB), which pierre-yves did just a few days earlier.

Bottom line: document-stores seem to have the lead when it comes to performance, but as always with nosql-solutions you have to keep the trade offs in mind.

update:
what i forgot to mention was: pierre was also discussing the difference in speed for case-sensitivity. a discussion i can't quite follow in full text searches, because in full-text searches you almost alyway want case-insensitive searches. Maybe the words you were searching were marked as important in CAPITAL LETTERs (with a small s!) and you wouldnt find them ever in a case-sensitvie approach.